# How do i create a virtual subdomain using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, virtual, cpanel, wildcard-subdomain

I would like to create virtual sub domains for clients who will have websites with us but the websites will be served from a single url in reality for example;

Customer requests website robshop.mywebsite.com so we create that on the fly but the content is actually served from mywebsite.com/websites/index.php?website=robshop

How do i do this?

Also my setup is with PHP and cPanel / WHM server.

Here is the htaccess code i have tried so far;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^robshop.instamob.co.uk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !instamob.co.uk/websites/index.php?website=robshop
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ instamob.co.uk/websites/index.php?website=robshop$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this in  a .htaccess file in your top directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^robshop.instamob.co.uk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !websites/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ websites/$1 [L]
```

If you need that $_GET submission, then you need to create a directory inside websites for each subdomain (ie instamob.co.uk/websites/robshop/) and then have an index.php for that directory that you want to show

Comment: i have placed the code into my htaccess but i am taken away to show the website does not exist.  Here is sample link: robshop.instamob.co.uk

Comment: try that... i removed the forward slash before the last $1

Comment: also please post the code in your original post that you placed in the file

Comment: tried those changes and no luck. I have added the code above. Could it be a dns issue with cPanel?