# create virtual subdomain from folder throught htaccess in shared hosting panel

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I want to do access www.domain.com/test as test.doamin.com and many more like test2.domain.com,test3.. by creating virtual subdomain through htaccess. I have tried and follow some link but no change found. I think is this because I have shared hosting and subdomains created from cpanel. please provide complete guidance on it.

I followed follwing links:

1. https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/how-to-create-virtual-dymanic-subdomain-in-php-with-htaccess.1521742/
2. [virtual subdomain htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092652/virtual-subdomain-htaccess)
3. [How do i create a virtual subdomain using htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440749/how-do-i-create-a-virtual-subdomain-using-htaccess)
4. http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3638570.htm

But still my problem is not solved. It always gives Ooops could not find..

Comment: Have you tried pinging the domain?  How are you setting up the DNS records?

Comment: Do I need to add server alias in httpd.conf so wild card DNS will work?

Comment: here is a post which can help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before, you must use cpanel to create the subdomain. If I remember right there was a dns issue with this code:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/%1 [P]
```

If you don't want to use cpanel creating wildcard domain entry such as *.domain.com should help.